the [red] tag exists, and it's for the "Red" language
Behold: red
Since that's a generic word, I find this tag's existence problematic.
Aside from that, apparently it's being used for discussing a programming language called "Red" (site, Wikipedia) that is related to rebol. Earliest question I can see is from 2010. Two questions last year, none so far this year... except for someone who literally referred to red things in the context of chroma subsampling.
I'd suggest

Getting those language users to discuss a better tag name. I'd propose red-lang or redlang (IDK what's customary, since go exists)
Retagging those questions or equivalent operation
Maybe making red unusable

What do you think?

"Since that's a generic word, I find this tag's existence problematic." I don't really feel like this holds weight either. "Rust" and "Python" are "generic" words, do you find the tags [[tag:rust]] and [[tag:python]] "problematic"?

@ThomA we don't tend to talk about snakes or oxidisation in programming context. But mentioning colours is common.

Rust is also a reddish colour, @VLAZ . I'm sure I could find plenty of other examples of tags of "generic" words, those were just 2 that immediately popped into my head.

What proportion of questions are mistagged i.e. using red as a colour?

I went through all questions tagged [red] and not any variation of [rebol]. I found only one which did not use "red" to refer to the language: why 'ed' also named 'red' in linux. I've removed the tag from it. I don't know whether there were previous misusages that were removed.

"I don't know whether there were previous misusages that were removed" Theoretically, one could get that (for non-deleted questions) from PostHistory in SEDE.

Can we, @RyanM? The PostHistory table is the information from the timeline, it doesn't store historical versions of the post. We'd need access to a PostRevision table.

the proportion of current mistags would not indicate the actual frequency of mistags. apparently that language tag is actively monitored. the question that caused me to notice this issue was retagged ("red" removed) rather quickly after posting. to find the true frequency of mistags, one would need to get all questions with revision 1 (or any revision) having the tag, and then judge manually.

We even renamed the oracle tag recently for being ambiguous even though it had existed since the beginning of the site basically, so why are we discussing if this should be renamed or not? It's ambiguous or it is going to be ambiguous some day, it should be red-lang.

my argument is that the tag itself is too generic to be useful. plenty of other generic tags were "handled" in some way that discourages/prevents their use. I think "red" simply falls in that same pattern. "python" and "rust" are good counterexamples because they, by their languages' popularity, are no longer generic. -- as for "oracle", I can see an argument for the company and its tech being split off because there are oracles in TCS/crypto. I wouldn't have an opinion on that either way, even if the decision hadn't been made already.

@Gimby Am I missing something then? I still see [[tag:oracle]].

Hello! I am actively monitoring [red] tag, and I'd say a ratio of wrong uses is like 80% at least. Of these 90% times it was used as a color and was removed, and there were some cases, where it was about [node-red] visual dataflow tool.

@ThomA [oracle] was renamed to [oracle-database] and there were too many questions and the merge failed which then caused other things to break and the renaming got reverted. It will get renamed in 6-8 weeks when (if) a developer renames it and retags everything.

The languages I think could have same problems - Go, C, R, F, D, Flow, Logo, Hack, Icon, Ring (from first 100 at TIOBE index)

@ThomA I don't know what you mean; the Text column on the PostHistory table is exactly that. See the schema.  Here's a query I wrote a while back that uses this information (note: not perfectly accurate, because my SQL leaves a bit to be desired).

What's wrong with the CSS here? Can we have the baseline of tags match the baseline of text?

@ThomasWeller that's a [[meta-tag:bug]] report which you should write as another question, not as a comment where it will not be seen by staff.

I was looking for a relationship between the history and the tags table (or at least a denormalised Tags column), @RyanM , as that's how the Posts table is designed. The text column in Posts also doesn't contain JSON but just the post content; "silly" me for expecting consistent design and naming from Stack Overflow.

If I see a new tag, then I'd normally read its tooltip as a first action. I would not assume [red] is a simple color, so nothing needs to be done here, really. Try it yourself, would you assume following tags are what they are (just random nouns): [chair], [sky], [bear], [moon], [door], [luck].. I believe the answer is no, you are going to read the tooltip of each such tag first. Correct?

@Sinatr "If I see a new tag, then I'd normally read its tooltip as a first action. I would not assume [red] is a simple color, so nothing needs to be done here, really."  that only works if you're the only user who applies tags. Which is not the case. If it worked like this then the tags clearly marked as "DO NOT USE" would not be used. But they are. Clarifying the name of the tag is a crucial way to reduce their misapplication.

@VLAZ, sure, then I propose [red-programming-language-and-not-color], that would 100% prevent users from missusing, right?

another fun example: [tag:ml] is constantly being misapplied to questions involving [tag:machine-learning]. mostly newbies do that. because they generally are unaware of or don't care about what a tag "should" be used and not used for. they just type things in that box because there is a box. from other sites I know that some newbies just pick a few tags from the top 5 suggested ones, regardless of meaning and applicability.

@Sinatr I don't understand what issue you have with the proposed rename to resort to snark.

@VLAZ, I have -lang issue. I am against [red-lang], but I am ok with my suggestion, because it solves the issue better, no?

@Sinatr What is your suggestion? Unless it's "assume users will read tooltips" which demonstrably does not happen with any consistency.

@Sinatr Could you clarify what "I have -lang issue" means?  What, exactly, is the issue with that?

The official site calls it Red Programming Language, the site url is red-lang.org, the social handle is @red_lang and the subreddit is /r/redlang. I don't see why disambiguating the tag to [red-lang] should be in any way controversial.

controversy is a niche form of amusement. I don't have a taste for it. -- I think there is sarcasm and cynicism. that's my benevolent take on parts of the debate.

I appologize to all for my sarcasm. After checking tags and searching for "lang", "red", "green", "blue", "magenta", etc. I now agree that [red] needs to be changed and -lang or lang suffixes are ok. Any such suffix should prevent users from misusing this tag as a color tag.

@Robotnik I would invite you to post that as an answer, because that hits the nail on the head.

On advice, I'm moving my comment into an answer:

The official site calls it Red Programming Language, the site url is red-lang.org, the social handle is @red_lang and the subreddit is /r/redlang.
Disambiguating the tag to red-lang should not be controversial in any way.

This is also what we've done in the past, IIRC, for common-word language tags.
